# Forms 3 or 4 Random Password Chars from password PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've seen a few sites asking the user to input 3 or 4 chars from their password randomly to gain access on a website account. I would like to know how to do this using PHP5, MySQL and possibly Ajax.

So, if I have a standard login form I'd have

```
username:
password:
Submit Button
```

but I'd like to do the following login form:

```
username:
Password (Inptut the following Chars:) Char 1[] Char 3[] char 7[]
Submit button
```

Chars 1, 3 & 7 are random and depending on length of orginal password.

If you've done a script like this and can shed some light on it or possible a full worknig script I can look at I'd be grateful.

Comment: So if your password is "foobar", and you're asked to insert chars 1, 3, and 5, you would insert "foa"? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: yes that is correct, the reason behind it; it adds a extra layer of security to the login, esp if you are loging in a none secure enviroment, you know the full passsword but it's never fully passed on the key strokes. a bit like using telphone banking they ask for random 3 - 4 chars from your telephone banking number. thanks about the best way to discribe it.

Comment: This is an interesting idea! But it does require the site to store the password unencrypted (or in an easily recoverable format). So the security risk isn't so much reduced as shifted around. Do you have enough confidence in the security of your server and DB that you're willing to take it on?

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought would be to select the random letters from splitting the users password up, and grabbing three random key indexes. These key indexes represent three letters in the password.

Using those key indexes, I build a smaller array where the key is the numerical index of the character in the password, and the value is the character itself.

```
$password = str_split( "stackoverflow" );
$randChar = array_rand( $password, 3 );

foreach ( $randChar as $key => $val )
  $letters[$val+1] = $password[ $val ];
```

At this point, our `$letters` array may look something like this:

```
Array
(
  [3] => a
  [5] => k
  [8] => e
)
```

Note. This is a random set. With this set, you would ask the user to provide characters as positions 3, 5, and 8. The values they submit can be compared to the values you randomnly generated.

Answer (score 1):

IN LOGIN FORM (using jquery):

```
var passChars = [SOME,SERVER,DEFINED,CHARS]; // some random chars set by server
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $.post("login.php", { user: $('#username').text(), pass: $('#pass').text(), 'chars[]':passChars}, function (data)
  {
    if(data.suc)
      window.location(data.location);
    else
      alert("Try again");
  }, "json");
});
```

IN LOGIN.PHP SCRIPT (where encrypt_pass is a defined password encryption function and LANDING_PAGE is the location you wish loggged in users to go to on success):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT unencrypted_pass, encrypted_pass FROM users WHERE user = '{$_POST['user']}'");
$pass = mysql_fetch_array($result);
for($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['chars']);$i++){
  $pass[0][(int)$_POST['chars'][$i]] = $_POST['pass'][$i];
}
if($pass[1] == encrypt_pass($pass[0])) // success
  echo json_encode(Array("suc"=>true, "location"=>LANDING_PAGE));
```

This assumes that the server knows your password so you can put the given chars into the string and then compare the string vs the encrypted version. This is the only way I can see this working because it is impossible to unencrypt passwords (if they are encrypted correctly).
I am wondering how this is useful, however...